# XML with image in Quartz Composer

Tags: xml, quartz-composer

I'm new to Quartz Composer. I want to import an XML feed, and show the image of the result.
This what one item of the XML looks like:

```
<item>
<title>test</title>
<link>
http://www....com
</link>
<description>
Test
</description>
<pubDate>Tue, 05 Aug 2014 06:57:00 GMT</pubDate>
<author>me</author>
<guid isPermaLink="false">
http://www....com
</guid>
<media:content type="image/jpeg" url="http://www.linktoimg.com">
<media:thumbnail url="http://www.linktothumb.com"/>
</media:content>
</item>
```

I've looking into this for days but without examples, I just can't get this to work.
Anyone who can point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There must be some examples in the Quartz samples.

But you can also check my old Time Machine screensaver (RSS version). It uses XML RSS feed and retrieves the text of it.

http://bodysoulspirit.weebly.com/time-machine-screensaver.html

Retriveing text or images is quite the same, just some changes in the Structure Key Members

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Got to do it ?

Once you get the Index and Key Member, you can isolate the Path using a string sorting descriptor.

I can post a File if you still looking how to make it.

Cheers